# Loading CSV in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml, kaggle

I'm attempting the Kaggle [Titanic Example](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) using SparkML and Scala.  I'm attempting to load the first training file but I am running into a strange error:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not read footer: java.lang.RuntimeException: file:/Users/jake/Development/titanicExample/src/main/resources/data/titanic/train.csv is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [44, 81, 13, 10]
```

The file is a `.csv` so I'm not sure why its expecting a Parquet file.

Here is my code:

```
object App {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("liveOrDie")
    .getOrCreate()

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val rawTrainingData = spark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load("src/main/resources/data/titanic/train.csv")

//    rawTrainingData.show()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have had a conflict with Scala versions in my `pom.xml` NOT my original code.  My `pom.xml` had multiple Scala versions seemingly causing issues.  I updated all dependencies that used Scala to the same version using a dynamic property `<scala.dep.version>2.11</scala.dep.version>` and that fixed the problem.

Comment: That was not my suggestion, the code you wrote doesn't make any sense since `load` does not return a `DataFrameReader`

Comment: Anyway I would remove the comment directed at me and then accept this as the answer so other SO users can learn from your experience.

Comment: Also fixing your dependency issue allowed the code you wrote in your original question to work or was it one of the other solutions? Please describe a) what needed to be fixed and b) what code you are using to load csvs now.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing input format. Either:

```
val rawTrainingData = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("src/main/resources/data/titanic/train.csv")
```

or

```
val rawTrainingData = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .format("csv")
  .load("src/main/resources/data/titanic/train.csv")
```

Comment: Yeah I notice that right after I entered the question.  I added the line `.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")` but that didn't do the trick.  I also tried both of your solutions, also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is expecting a parquet file because that is what the [default file type](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#generic-loadsave-functions).

If you are using Spark < 2.0, you will need to use [Spark-CSV](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). Otherwise if you are using Spark 2.0+ you will be able to use the [`DataFrameReader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) by using `.csv(..fname..)` instead of `.load(..fname..)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a dependency jar from databricks into your pom . Lower version spark doesn't provide api to read csv. Once you download you can write something like below..

```
val df = sqlContext.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
// Use first line of all files as header
.option("inferSchema", "true")
// Automatically infer data types
.load("cars.csv")
```

Ref url: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I had that in there.  In fact, now that I have it working, I can comment the Databricks dependency out and the program will still work.  I should note that I'm using Spark 2.0.

Comment: thats awesome and thanks for letting me know about spark 2.0 support.